# How can I show datas on gridview when selecting a dropdownlist in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdownlist and a gridview. When Dropdownlist is selected , gridview should show the data.

Comment: do you want to populate gridview based on dropdown selected value??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that's gonna work for you

http://www.facebook.com/groups/314912835194902/doc/406584239361094/

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void DropDownListChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridView.DataSource = GetDataSource();
    gridView.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write an event **SelectedIndexChanged="ddlChanged"** and write your logic under it.

```
protected void ddlChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridView.DataSource = GetData();
    gridView.DataBind();
}
```

Make sure that you have **AutoPostBack="true"** on DropDownList. Otherwise it will not fire the event.